# Not able to take response body data for assertions while performing operations using rest-assured with java

Tags: java, arrays, testng, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Following is Response body:

```
{
    "Updated_Fields": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
    ],
    "Invalid_Fields": [
        "cd",
        "ab"
    ]
}
```

I want to check that whether response body has

1. two fields in invalid_field block
2. 'cd' and 'ab' should be there in invalid_field block

```java
JSONArray JSONResponseBody = new JSONArray(response.body().asString());

Assert.assertEquals(JSONResponseBody.getJSONObject(0).getString("Invalid_Fields"), "cd");

response.jsonPath().param("Invalid_Fields", "cd");

assertThat( response.asString(), hasJsonPath("Invalid_Fields.ab"));
```

Getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can use a library like gson to convert String to Java object and then apply standard Java logic ( sample below )

[Gson Maven Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

> private static final List INVALID_DATA = Arrays.asList("cd", "ab");
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> {
>     String input = "{ \"Updated_Fields\": [ \"a\", \"b\", \"c\", \"d\" ], \"Invalid_Fields\": [ \"cd\", \"ab\" ] }";
>     Gson gson = new Gson();
>     FieldData data = gson.fromJson(input, FieldData.class);
>     System.out.println(isInvalidFields(data.Invalid_Fields));
> }
>
> private static boolean isInvalidFields(List<String> Invalid_Fields) {
>     if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Invalid_Fields) || Invalid_Fields.size() != 2) {
>      return false;   
>     }
>     return Invalid_Fields.containsAll(INVALID_DATA);
> }
> ```

Definiton of class mapping to this data:

```
public class FieldData
{

    public List<String> Updated_Fields;

    public List<String> Invalid_Fields;

}
```